# How to extract number of followers of a user from twitter website using WebView in Android?

Tags: android, html, twitter, webview, android-sdk-2.1

I want to program an Android app -for android 2.1 and above- that does not have to be authorized to extract just the number of followers of a twitter user.

I was thinking about using the WebView to load the twitter URL of the user and then I extract the content of the web page and then the number of followers.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution might be to use the [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) library. If you do, it's as simple as:

```
Twitter myTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
long[] followerIds = myTwitter.getFollowersIDs("screenName", -1).getIDs();
```

The number of followers is the length of the follower ID array;